# mobile html5 offline caching dynamic pages

Tags: html, coldfusion, web-applications, offline-caching

I am making a web app that is database driven and am having a hard time trying to figure out a way to cache article pages.

I've thought of just doing a cfquery to loop through all the article IDs to give me a page path (e.g. /?page=article&article_id=#id#) but from what I know of html5 caching is that if anything changes in the manifest file it will download everything all over again.

If updateready keeps getting triggered does it slow down the page significantly?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't slow things down too much, because all that should be happening in the background, but it's not really the best approach.  The app cache isn't intended for storing dynamic data, it's much better for static content.  I would recommend caching a container page and then load the content into it with AJAX/JavaScript.  Use [local storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute) to keep your data for offline use on the client side.